# Larvel Relacion One to One

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

estoy intentando realizar una relacion One to One de mi tabla customers con mi tabla customer_groups

mi tabla customers tiene las siguentes columnas:

id, customer_group_id, fullname, etc...

customer_groups por su parte tiene las siguientes columnas

id, name, percentage, etc...

en mi controller tengo en show()

```
public function show($id)
    {

        $customer = Customer::findOrFail($id);

        
        return view('customer::show', ['customer' => $customer]);
    }
```

mi Model CustomerGroup:

```
class CustomerGroup extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =[

        "name", "percentage", "is_active"
    ];
    
    protected static function newFactory()
    {
        return \Modules\Customer\Database\factories\CustomerGroupFactory::new();
    }


    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Customer\Entities\Customer');
    }
    
}
```

Mi modelo Customer es el siguiente

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    protected $table='customers';

    protected $primaryKey="id";

    public $timestamps=true;

    protected $dates = ['birthday'];

    protected $fillable =[
        'customer_group_id',
        'fullname',
        'cuil',
        'num_doc',
        'validator',
        'phone',
        'mobile',
        'whatsapp',
        'email',
        'class',
        'note',
        'photo'
    ];

    protected $guarded =[

    ];

    /**
     * Get the phone record associated with the user.
     */
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Modules\Customer\Entities\CustomerGroup');
    }
 
}
```

en mi vista quiero colocar

{{$customer->fullname}} y me retorna el nombre sin problema

{{$customer->group->name}} aca debería retornarme lo que está en la columna nombre de dicho cliente... pero me tira el siguiente error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customer_groups.customer_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `customer_groups` where `customer_groups`.`customer_id` = 1 and `customer_groups`.`customer_id` is not null limit 1)
```

Mi migracion de la tabla customers es la siguiente:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_group_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('customer_group_id')->references('id')->on('customer_groups')->onDelete('SET NULL');
```

Hice varias pruebas pero nada que funciona...

Mi idea sería que ademas de poder obtener esos campos en particular, luego que pueda filtrar según  el tipo de customer_group tambien...

por lo que quise aplicar en Customer One to One y en CustomerGroup OneToMany pero tampoco he conseguido lo contrario.

PD: habia olvidado seleccionar el ID en el Model..

```
return $this->hasOne('Modules\Customer\Entities\CustomerGroup', 'id');
```

Ahora me retorna una respuesta al colocar {{$customer->group->name}}
pero no me retorna el nombre que le corresponde al id en customer_group_id

por ejemplo... al usuario con id 1, devuelve el nombre del grupo con id 1

al usuario con id 2, devuelve el nombre del grupo con id 2...

y asi sucesivamente...

Answer (score 0):

Con la linea `{{$customer->group->name}}` quieres acceder al nombre del grupo de clientes, no es así? Yo creo que el problema son las relaciones que estás haciendo en los modelos. Si estoy entendiendo bien tu problema, cada cliente puede pertenecer a varios grupos de clientes, y cada grupo de clientes puede tener muchos clientes, por lo tanto la relacion de clientes a grupo de clientes sería más bien 1:M, y la relacion de grupo de clientes a clientes sería M:M.
Por otro lado, recuerda que en las relaciones de los modelos de laravel, las funciones como hasOne pueden recibir un segundo y tercer parametro que corresponden al ID de la tabla foránea, y el ID de la tabla local respectivamente. Es decir, hasOne('Modules\Customer\Entities\CustomerGroup', 'id_foráneo','id_local');
Supongo que sabes que si colocaste nombres distintos a esas ID, debes definir éstos parametros ya que Laravel buscará por defecto el campo ID.. Lo comento porque creo que en tu tabla customer_group el id lleva por nombre customer_id (o por lo menos ese es el campo que se está buscando en la consulta SQL), y por ahí puede venir el problema de la consulta.

Intenta modificando tu modelo de customer_group asi

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Modules\Customer\Entities\Customer','customer_group_id','customer_id');
}
```

Y el modelo customer asi

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Modules\Customer\Entities\CustomerGroup','customer_id','customer_group_id');
}
```

Comment: Hola te pongo en contexto, 1 usuario puede pertenecer a 1 grupo.... y 1 grupo puede pertenecer a muchos usuarios, ejemplo Usuario1 -> Consumidor, Usuario2->Gremio, Usuario3->Consumidor.